# Navbar Links are not working in Internet explorer 11

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, internet-explorer-11

The following navbar is not clickable in Internet Explorer. I have been using Bootstrap 3.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<!-- force IE8+ into standards mode -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>XYZ Management Pvt Ltd.</title>

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/management.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
<link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">    

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

At the end I have also put this

```
<script src="http://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="http://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Nav link is not clickable at all in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Did you ever find a reason for this? I have been researching this issue for the past few days and have been unable to find anything that has been useful. Interested to know if you were able to resolve the problem..

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` on the first line of your html.

Comment: I do have that...I missed it while copying. It is not working at all. Just now, I checked in IE8 and it's all messed up there also.